# convert HTML to PDF with dynamic image using PD4ML

Tags: java, html, pdf, image

We are using PD4ML library to convert HTML to PDF. Is there any way with which I can include a image from the internet in my HTML to convert it into PDF.
I am having problem in getting the image into PDF. I tried using base parameter in the PD4ML library but that didn't worked out.
May be I am doing something wrong or PD4ML doesn't support including image from the internet.
Because when I discussed my problem with other colleagues, found out that when we use the image from local server it gets to the PDF but image from internet don't.
I am bound to use PD4ML, so solution with PD4ML only will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PD4ML support Images! You can include the image with `<img src="">`. For a project we include a base64 image in the html document.

this is the code:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,BASE64PICTURE" width="285" height="215" />
```